# Segmentation fault with rake db:create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault

I'm running into a segmentation fault when I do rake db:create in a

The error output is:

```
/home/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

Aborted
```

I tried following the sample tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I get the same error with a brand new project.

Comment: Did you install your gems with bundler? The mismatch of ruby versions brings this: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/24/a-tale-of-abort-traps-or-always-question-your-assumptions/ to mind (a longish read, but interesting). Try reinstalling your sqlite3 gem. You might want to update bundler and rvm first, or at least `rehash`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing that. I installed Rails a while ago, and I followed a tutorial somewhere to supposedly keep the versions matched through RVM, but I guess it didn't work. Do you know where I could find the correct way to uninstall/reinstall it and/or fix RVM?

Comment: `gem uninstall sqlite3` followed by `bundle install` should work (if this is the problem). Do `rvm get latest`, `rvm reload` and `gem update bundle` first to be sure.

Comment: Hmm, not quite. I was able to get rake db:create to work, but now rake db:migrate coughs up, with the exact same error message. ruby -v and which ruby both point to 1.9.2, so I'm not sure where 1.8.7 is getting thrown in there.

Comment: Maybe your `GEM_HOME` is messed up somehow. Are you using the current version of `rvm`? There have been a few releases that were somewhat less than satisfactory.

Comment: Solved [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274409/rails-annotate-segmentation-fault/7985104#7985104

Comment: I see the same problem. I tried the solution from @matt, still got the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274409/rails-annotate-segmentation-fault/7985104#7985104 solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should probably try rake db:migrate