# Rails Annotate Segmentation Fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, segmentation-fault, annotate

There are a handful of questions that sort of skirt around this question, but nothing that really gets to what I'm looking for.

After I `bundle install` my Gemfile, listed below, I run `annotate` and come up with the following error:

```
/Users/nickcoelius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@nick/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10]

Abort trap
```

I'm running ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0.7, and Mac OS 10.6.7.  Thoughts?

Ruby -v: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10]
Rails -v: Rails 3.0.7

Gem list:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.7)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7)
annotate (2.4.0)
annotate-models (1.0.4)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.14)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.2)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
spork (0.9.0.rc5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
webrat (0.7.3)
```

Comment: Did you install the correct libraries for the native sqlite3 gem? If you have the incorrect architecture that would cause a segfault.

Comment: Also, try restarting your terminal and can you provide the output of `ruby -v` and `rails -v`

Comment: What do you mean by "correct libraries"?  I'm a rails novice, obviously, so I'm not sure what you're driving at.  Edited post with rails/ruby -v.

Comment: Side note: Thanks for the edits, but how do you get scrollbar boxes in the first place?  SO newb as well :-/

Comment: Try upgrading `sqlite3-ruby` (latest version is 1.3.3): `gem update && bundle update`

Comment: I ran gem update && bundle update, got no errors, but did not apparently update sqlite3-ruby.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error probably were caused by some rvm crash.
I had the same problem and after a hour Googling, I found the following solution:

1. Uninstall all gems: `gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`
2. `gem install rake`
3. `gem install bundler`
4. `bundle install`

Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `bundle exec annotate`?