# Rails issue starting server on Mountain Lion "[BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really new to coding so please pardon my inexperience. 
I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial, and I'm stuck on the part where you're supposed to make a server.
The instruction is to simply type:

$ rails server

The error message I'm getting is:

`/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`

I'm confused as to why it says ruby 1.8.7 even though i'm using 1.9.3. Please help me fix this problem. I'm a complete beginner so please keep it simple.

Comment: are you sure you are using the version you think you are?  try a `ruby -v`

Comment: also, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077790/segmentation-fault-with-rake-dbcreate-in-rails ?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response. This is what I get so I'm pretty sure I am using 1.9.3. ("ruby 1.9.3p429"). I followed the steps in the link you posted but that didn't help. Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: how are you including `sqlite3` in your Gemfile?  you might have to specify a specific version. `gem 'sqlite3', '~> version.here'`, also, did you do a `bundle install`?  Every time you change around your Gemfile, you need to do a `bundle install`

Comment: which solution worked? i'll have an answer so we can accept and close this question.  was it the `bundle install` ?

Comment: it was the the 'bundle install' that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably didn't bundle your gem before running your server.  Try

```
bundle install
```

then run `rails s`